# setting a class attribute in page_load on asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to set the class attribute of a list item on page load.

```
Dim liItem As HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("default"),          HtmlGenericControl)
    liItem.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
```

This code doesn't work, not quite sure why.
This is the error it is generating
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the control is in the master page you should be doing:

```
Dim liItem As HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Me.Master.FindControl("default"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the exception doesn't get much clearer. The NullReferenceException indicates here that `liItem` is null. That means that either there is no control in the page called "default" (likely) or that the DirectCast didn't work (less likely, but also possible). One thing to keep in mind is the control is not likely to be embedded in the Page's control collection.

If the control labeled "default" is contained within a Panel or similar container control, you'll need to use the FindControl method of that particular control. Another method of getting the control would be to write an extension method to override the FindControl method to be recursive (a potentially heavy method).

**Edit:**

When accessing items from the master page in this manner, I prefer to take the guess work out of it. I typically will set a property in my master page that holds the value or control in question such as:

```
Public Property LI_Default() As HtmlGenericControl
    Get
        Return Me.Default  ' Assumes the name specified in the question
    End Get
End Property
```

Now this isn't immediately accessible by pages that make use of the master page, so you have to declare the master type inside the aspx page itself:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Path/To/My/Master.master" %>
```

With this declaration, you now have access to the property you created, and you don't need to bother "finding" the control anymore.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Me.Master IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Master.LI_Default.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The li's are in the master page. I am trying to set the class attribute to "active" when a li is clicked on. Here is the code in the master page. I am trying to set the attribute from  a call to a content page in the page load event

Comment: @dinotom: I'll post an edit showing my preferred method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is that the "default" control declaration (in the page) does not have an ID and does not have the runat="server" directive. Both of these items must be set in the control in order for FindControl to find the control.

Comment: runat="server' is set and the id of the li is "default" The li's are part of a <ul> in the master page. How do I look for the control after the master and content pages are merged? or do I do it before?

Comment: I think that you need to recursively search through the controls. Create a new recursive method that accepts a ControlCollection as a parameter and pass it the page's Controls collection. In the method, loop through each of the controls in the collection, then if a given control in the collection has Controls, call your method with that control's Controls collection. I usually set a return value on the method and bail out back up the call chain once I've found the control I'm looking for.